# Qt5.1.0 Static linking, "This application cannot be statically linked to the fftreal library"

Tags: qt, static, qt-creator, qt5

These are the exact steps that I took:

1. Installed Qt 5.1.0 from this link and placed it in `C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\`: http://download.qt-project.org/development_releases/qt/5.1/5.1.0-rc2/qt-windows-opensource-5.1.0-rc2-mingw48_opengl-x86-offline.exe
2. Extracted sources and put it into `C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Source\`: http://download.qt-project.org/development_releases/qt/5.1/5.1.0-rc2/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.0-rc2.zip
3. Installed Active Python 2.7 in: `C:\Python27\` (Added to PATH), Ruby 200 in: `C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Source\Ruby200\` (ticked the option to add to PATH when installing), and Perl64 in: `C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Source\`
4. Installed only "Client C API Library" portion from mysql-5.5.32-win32.msi: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/
5. Ran `Qt5.1.0 for Desktop (MinGW 4.8 32 bit)` as admin and typed `configure -static -qt-sql-mysql -I C:\MySql\include -L C:\MySql\lib` all in one line. Like so: [image: command line that I ran]

I noticed this [image: -LC:\MySql\lib L and C stuck together] when it prompted me to run `mingw32-make` (just above "WARNING:" It says my additional libraries are located in -LC:\MySql\lib without a space between L and C.

6. I disregarded that and ran `mingw32-make` after the configure was done.

After awhile, I get this error (at the bottom of image).

[image: This application cannot be statically linked to the fftreal library]

What am I missing/not doing? I need some guidance. If there is some sort of 5.1.0 Static build guide that I can reference, that would be great! Thank you all ahead of time.

If someone is willing to guide me through this whole process to successfully create Qt statically, I am more than willing to give all the points that this site allows me to said person. (If I'm breaking some sort of rule please disregard this last statement then)

Edit: My PATH has this `%APPDATA%\Python\Scripts;C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Source\Ruby200\bin;C:\cygwin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\;C:\Python27\`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It failed trying to build one of the examples. Try adding `-nomake expamples` to your configure line.

Also. I don't think the open source license allows you to build static linked libraries.

Comment: only for personal use and thanks for the tip. If it works and I build it successfully ill add bounty and you give to you. testing it out now

Comment: Ok, I think it worked, It didn't give me any errors, how would I make a standalone exe now? Do you mind helping?

Answer (score 1):

`Qt 5.0.*` have had some bugs in static compile of Qt that does not take compilation process successfully, if they are get solved, so you can build them statically, I don't know your linker error associated with mentioned bugs or not.

Reported bugs:

[Compiling static QT libraries with /MT using MSVC2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975165/compiling-static-qt-libraries-with-mt-using-msvc2010/16198914#16198914)

Comment: im using 5.1.0 after realizing 5.0.* didnt work :P thanks for the warning though, and hopefully this will help others too