# Build program with QT 5.0.2 on Windows

Tags: qt, compiler-construction, build, exe

I want to build my program(developed with QT 5.0.2) and give it to some friends.

How can I process?

I tried `qmake -project` and `qmake` in my folder with the `*.cpp` files, but it didn't create any exe.

This is my `.pro` file

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-08-03T18:53:41
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = target
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        class1.cpp\
        class2.cpp\
        class3.cpp\
        class4.cpp

HEADERS  += class1.h\
            class2.h\
            class3.h\
            class4.h

FORMS    += class1.ui\
            class3.ui
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tutorial for building project on Windows](http://godhc.wordpress.com/2012/06/10/build-your-qt-project-on-windows-and-mac-osx/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you compiled your `QtSDK` statically? if yes, you can build your project as `static linking`, either you can't, if your are manually download your `Qt` repository from `qt-project.org`, it is a `shared` version of Qt, you should remove the line contain `CONFIG += static` and compile your project as shared and add the line below to your `.pro` file:

```
QT    += core gui
```

Note:

Use `Qt Creator` as `Qt Framework IDE` to manage and build your projects, it's really handy and great tool, another way is use `Visual Studio Add-In` that integrates with VStudio, if you are professional in Qt architecture, you can use makefile base building of Qt with`qmake`.

Comment: Yeah I downloaded my QT from qt-project.org. How can I compile my project as shared?

Comment: acutally my `.pro file` was wrong (I think, qmake overrode it). I updated it. How am I supposed to build my project? If I click on the build button(left corner down), he will build it, but the release folder is empty. If I go to the debug folder and copy all this shit, I can execute it, but I want something small and not all the cpp files and so on in a folder.

Comment: yes, you can build it with debug or release mode, but this is shared compile, you must copy required DLLs to your app folder, but if you want to static build, you need to static compile of Qt repository, but there is some bugs in static build of Qt with the versions 4.8 and above (I'm not trying Qt new released version 5.1!), the reported bugs in here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16198914/1789729   but version 4.7 works for static build.

Comment: I hadn't to copy some DDLs. I just copied the complete Folder `C:\QT\<version>\workspace\build-<app_name>-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug` to somewhere else and could execute it. Is there an opportunity to merge all the files and have like `one big .dll` and `1 .exe`?

Comment: No, you should use shared library, read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15569097/1789729